# AWSWrangler chucksize with data type conversion

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that reads in json files and then converts to parquet from S3. I came across an issue where if the files is greater than 1GB, lambda runs out of memory. I'm using awswrangler to read in the json and writing to parquet and after doing some research found chunksize to read the files in chunk. The issue I'm having is after reading in the json file, I need to either convert all datatypes to string or there's scenarios where I convert them to specific datatypes. I've been getting these two error messages:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'empty'
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

My code on reading the json with chunksize and trying to convert to all strings which works fine without the chunksize

```
dfs = wr.s3.read_json(path=[s3_json_location], lines=True, orient='records', chunksize=1000)
dfs = dfs.astype(str)
```

Code with specified datatypes

```
dfs = wr.s3.read_json(path=[s3_json_location], lines=True, orient='records', chunksize=1000)
if 'column1' in dfs.columns: 
   dfs['column1']=dfs['column1'].apply(str)
if 'column5' in dfs.columns:
   dfs['column5']=dfs['column5'].fillna(0)
   dfs['column5']=dfs['column5'].apply(int)
```

Since chunksize returns generator object, I'm not sure how can I change the datatype. Any help is appreciated

UPDATE:
After doing more research, I updated my code to this:

```
nRows = 0
for dfChunk in wr.s3.read_json(path=[s3_json_location], lines=True, orient='records', chunksize=1000)
   nRows = nRows + len(dfChunk)
   print("processed {0}".format(nRows))
   dfChunk = dfChunk.astype(str)
   wr.s3.to_parquet(df=dfChunk, path=Path, dataset=True, mode='append')
```

How would I convert the whole chunk to parquet because right now it created multiple parquet file instead of one parquet file